# How can I hide/show components by touching not button but screen on React Native?

Tags: react-native, components, screen, show-hide

I'm learning React Native for the first time. I want to implement a function to show/hide the component by touching the screen, not a specific button.

(Please check the attached file for the example image.)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kgDx.png)

In this code, I've tried to make a function. if I touch the screen (`<View style={style.center}>`, then show/hide the `renderChatGroup()` and `renderListMessages()` included in `<View style={style.footer}>`. The source code is below.

In my code, it works. However, the two `<View>` tag is not parallel. the footer view is center View's child.

I want to make them parallel. but I couldn't find the contents about controlling another `<View>` tag, not a child. In this code, I used setState, then I couldn't control another the below `<View>`.

Of course, I tried Fragment tag, but it didn't render anything.

How could I do implement this function? Please help me!

```html
    export default class Streamer extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          isVisibleFooter: true,
        };
    }
    
    renderChatGroup = () => {
    const { isVisibleFooter } = this.state;
    if (isVisibleFooter) {
      return (
        <ChatInputGroup
          onPressHeart={this.onPressHeart}
          onPressSend={this.onPressSend}
          onFocus={this.onFocusChatGroup}
          onEndEditing={this.onEndEditing}
        />
      );
    }
    return null;
  };
  
  onPressVisible = () => {
    const { isVisibleFooter } = this.state;
    this.setState(() => ({ isVisibleFooter: !isVisibleFooter }));
  };

  render() {
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          <SafeAreaView style={styles.contentWrapper}>
            <View style={styles.header} />
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.onPressVisible}>
              <View style={styles.center}>
                <View style={styles.footer}>
                  {this.renderChatGroup()}
                  {this.renderListMessages()}
                </View>
              </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          </SafeAreaView>
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I would highly recommend you use react native with functional components and React Hooks as they alternative will soon will be deprecated.

Since `onPress` is not available on the `View` Component, you would need to replace it with `TouchableWithoutFeedback` as you have already done in your code.

For Showing/Hiding a view you would need to use a conditional operator.

```js
export default class Streamer extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          isVisibleFooter: true,
        };
    }
    
    renderChatGroup = () => {
    const { isVisibleFooter } = this.state;
    if (isVisibleFooter) {
      return (
        <ChatInputGroup
          onPressHeart={this.onPressHeart}
          onPressSend={this.onPressSend}
          onFocus={this.onFocusChatGroup}
          onEndEditing={this.onEndEditing}
        />
      );
    }
    return null;
  };
  
  onPressVisible = () => {
    this.setState(() => ({ isVisibleFooter: !isVisibleFooter }));
    const { isVisibleFooter } = this.state;
  };

  render() {
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          <SafeAreaView style={styles.contentWrapper}>
            <View style={styles.header} />
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.onPressVisible}>
              <View style={styles.center}>
                {isVisibleFooter && <View style={styles.footer}>
                  {this.renderChatGroup()}
                  {this.renderListMessages()}
                </View>}
              </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          </SafeAreaView>
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    }
  }
```

Here you can see i have replaced

```js
<View style={styles.footer}>
    {this.renderChatGroup()}
    {this.renderListMessages()}
</View>
```

with

```js
{isFooterVisible && <View style={styles.footer}>
    {this.renderChatGroup()}
    {this.renderListMessages()}
</View>}
```

stating that to only display the `Footer` View when

```js
const isFooterVisible = true;
```